# How to enable (progress bar / loading icon) for a frozen screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, freeze, jquery-deferred

I have a **webapp that loads an csv file** to view in the app. I tried loading a large file and it **freezes the screen** for some time, and then finally loads the csv file and displays the csv contents. I have a rotating loading icon on the file input button and this also freezes and stops rotating until the screen unfreezes.

I found that jQuery has **deferred objects** to keep a **promise and solve** it later. Can I use this method (deferred) to keep the screen normal and then solve it later once the file has finished with the parsing and the loading icon can animate rotating until the file has loaded? Can I also use a progress bar using this solution?

Here are some of the functions that parse the csv file and might be causing the screen to freeze.

I have `$.each(ARRAY, function());` functions, and `ARRAY.forEach();` mostly, and need to add preloaders and deferred promise objects to these parsing functions. I'm also using `papa.parse()`  javascript library for the same. Anyway to script these functions to allow unfreezing the screen?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Web Worker.

**Long answer:**

Technically you can make the CSV parsing function `async` then sprinkle in `await new Promise(setTimeout);` to prevent it from blocking.  But this will make it take longer to parse.

The best solution is to use a web worker to parse the CSV.  This offloads the work to a different thread than the main one, where it won't cause anything to freeze.

Comment: Thanks! Could you allow any information if web workers are client based or server based? Also, any suggestions on Javascript based web workers? My app is HTML5 javascript based and I might need the server based worker to allow javascript programming. I don't prefer nodejs, cause it requires a platform different from HTML5. I can use PHP although if that allows any javascript. Does Google provide any workers? I could use Google cause Google has better subscription plan for their api's.

Comment: A Web Worker is just the term for a separate JavaScript thread in the browser.  How to start a new thread in your server will depend entirely on what kind of server you're using, but you don't need a new thread on your server to prevent the client's UI from freezing while the server is working.